# Angular2 static class Dependency Injection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have a class named "Api" with static methods whose main purpose is to create a layer over the Http module and add some extra functionalities.

However, I can't see how I can use DI to inject the Http module into it.
Providing `http : Http` inside the constructor won't do anything because the class is static.

One way for sure would be to pass the Http object to the function calls, but that is a bad solution.

Other thing I could probably do is make the class Injectable, but in this case I would have to inject it to most of my components. Would this be the best way to go with?

Comment: I think the only sane way is to make the static methods instance methods. As a hack you could create a service class that forwards instance method calls to the static methods of the original class.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I thought so as well. And then make it an injectable class, right?

Comment: Exactly. . . .  . . . .

Comment: You'll thank yourself for using injection when it comes time to testing. This is one of the major (even primary) benefits of DI